# refrencing a map checkbox with javascript, that does not have an ID

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Examples I have found about checking a checkbox with javascript have all referenced an ID. I need to check the box of a checkbox that is listed below.

```
<input data-marker-category="1" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

Example that uses ID = `$("#_1").prop("checked", true);`

The full code listed below

```
<div class="wpgmp_tab_item" data-container="wpgmp-category-tab-item"><input data-marker-category="1" value="1" type="checkbox"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wpgmp_cat_title accordion accordion-close">Access Points<span class="arrow"></span></a></div>
```

Comment: If it doesn't have an id, what other characteristics make it uniquely identifiable?

Comment: As far as I can tell the category = 1 and the value of =1  The other checkboxes have a different category number and value

Comment: Then `docuent.querySelector("input[data-marker-category=1][value=1]")` (possibly also `[type=checkbox]`) should do instead of `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Or that, if you want to use jQuery for some reason, yes.

Comment: $("input[data-marker-category=1][value=1]").prop("checked", true);  Thanks for your help so far....this checks the boxes but doesn't actually show the map items like when you check it manually?  I just inputted this into my browser console but not in a script on the site, will try that next.